# Where/How do I put the error message in a html when a textbox is left empty

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there a specific tag to use? or do I just put it in a script code. the error message is supposed to pop up when a user leaves a textbox blank. This is what I had

```
<p>
    <label> First Name:<input type = "fnametbx" name = "fnametbx" size = "25" />
    </label>
</p>
```

I replaced it with the only one i can find in my book, which is a validator tool but it's not working, there is nowhere for the user to input

First Name:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="fnametbx" runat="server"
            style="margin-left: 56px">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="fnametbxValidator"
        ControlToValidate="fnametbx"
        Display="Static"
        runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
```

Comment: The question is not clear. You have a html input and a `TextBox` with the same ID/name. You need to use the `TextBox` which is rendered as html-input type=text.

Comment: The label is what I had, the textbox code is what was in my book and I replaced it with, but then there was no more label for the user to input information

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label> &nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" style="margin-left:56px"></asp:TextBox>       <br /> 
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtFirstNameValidator" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnWriteFirstName" runat="server" Text="Write First Name" />
```

All I have for the code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub btnWriteFirstName_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWriteFirstName.Click

    Response.Write("Hi there, " & txtFirstName.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you put that, in what tag or? Also, where did you get that from, I don't remember seeing that in my book?